# How to convert foreach() Mysql select into HTML form

Tags: php, html, sql

I am working on a small course registration system. I have a table called 20182019carryovertbl I select students carry over fron the table and its working well. I need to convert the selected info to an HTML form with submit button( This will go into another table 20192020coursestbl). How d i set name for my inputs

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Register course</th>
      <th>Course Title</th>
      <th>Corse Code</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>Lecturer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <?php $sql = "SELECT * from  20182019carryovertbl WHERE matricno = '$matno' ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="checkbox" name="reg1" value="1" class="custom-control-input"></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo htmlentities($result->coursetitle);?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo htmlentities($result->coursecode);?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo htmlentities($result->unit);?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo htmlentities($result->lecturer);?>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <?php $cnt=$cnt+1; }} ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your unique key from database like Id:

```
<td> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="reg<?php echo $result->id;" value="1"class="custom-control-input">
</td>
```

and it's gonna be unique name